# What can I do about uncounterable spells?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I cast [Fling](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=271225), sacrificing my only creature to kill my opponent.  My opponent responds with [Last Word](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=50929), which will win the game the other way.  Last Word says "This spell can't be countered."  What else can I do about it besides countering it to prevent my plans from being foiled?  (I'd really like to have the last word here.)

---

Historic Note: before of the April 2018 rules change, uncounterable spells with targets used to actually have different wording (still visible on the printed cards) implying that they still could be countered.  For example, Last Word said:

> Last Word can't be countered by spells or abilities.

Meanwhile Akroma, Angel of Fury said:

> Akroma, Angel of Fury can't be countered.

Comment: Please don't put spaces just inside your `[mtg:]` formatting - instead of `[mtg: Fling]`, write `[mtg:Fling]`. It can break the link, at least for those of us using [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) to [fix our auto link feature](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1152/).

Comment: Since the link *still* does not go directly to the page, it would probably be better to just link directly to the card page. I made that change here.

Comment: @murgatroid99 You should totally get SOUP. The fix in it takes us straight to the page. :D

Comment: Even if it helps, we should optimize for the common visitor, not the power user who knows about stuff like that.

Comment: Since you answered your own question, I felt comfortable editing the title to ask what you appear to be looking for. Feel free to roll it back if I was wrong.

Comment: Am very confused why the title was changed.

Comment: @Waterseas I believe the edit was based on Rainbolt's understanding of the answer (and the relevant rules) as explained in http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/24143/409; if the ideas in that question had been correct the edit would've made sense.

Comment: An interesting example is [Gilded Drake](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=5837) which contains Oracle text "This ability can't be countered except by spells and abilities." since the ability targets but needs to sacrifice if it fails.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I think optimizing for the common visitor, in this case, means "Yell at the devs to patch the system so [mtg] links aren't broken constantly anymore."

Comment: @AlexP Sure, that would definitely be the best. But I don't have control over that, so in the meantime I think the second best solution is to fix links so that they work for all visitors within the system as it exists.

Comment: "What else can I do about it?" Don't have winning the game be dependent on a single card?

Comment: @Acccumulation This is an update of the question to still be relevant in light of the 2018 rules change.  The question was, and remains, about things that can be done in response to uncounterable spells.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is now no way to "counter" an uncounterable spell, but you can achieve the same effect by preventing it from resolving.  The easiest way to do this is to cause all of its targets to be invalid:

> 608.2b If the spell or ability specifies targets, it checks whether the targets are still legal. A target that’s no longer in the zone it was in when it was targeted is illegal. Other changes to the game state may cause a target to no longer be legal; for example, its characteristics may have changed or an effect may have changed the text of the spell. If the source of an ability has left the zone it was in, its last known information is used during this process.  **If all its targets, for every instance of the word “target,” are now illegal, the spell or ability doesn’t resolve.** It’s removed from the stack and, if it’s a spell, put into its owner’s graveyard.

There are 2 ways to do this:

1. Change the target of the uncounterable spell.  You can prevent Last Word from resolving by changing it's target, such as via [Redirect](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRedirect%5d).  By using Redirect to change Last Word to target Redirect, Last Word will not resolve, as described in this ruling:

> If you cast Redirect targeting a spell that targets a spell on the stack (like Cancel does, for example), you can’t change that spell’s target to itself. You can, however, change that spell’s target to Redirect. If you do, that spell won’t resolve when it tries to resolve because Redirect will have left the stack by then.

2. Make the targeted object a new object.  If the targeted object is a spell, you can use [Ertai's Meddling](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bErtai%27s%5d%2b%5bMeddling%5d) will bring your spell back later when their spell is no longer on the stack.  If the targeted object is a permanent (such as a creature targeted by [Inescapable Blaze](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bInescapable%20Blaze%5d)), exiling it and returning it to the battlefield (such as with [Momentary Blink](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMomentary%20Blink%5d)) will cause it to become a new permanent and no longer targeted by the spell.

As far as uncounterable spells in general (like [Thrun, the Last Troll](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThrun%2c%20the%20Last%20Troll%5d)), there are a few other ways you can deal with them while they are on the stack (none of which are technically countering):

- You can exile the spell, such as with [Time Stop](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTime%20Stop%5d), [Mindbreak Trap](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMindbreak%20Trap%5d), or [Ertai's Meddling](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bErtai%27s%5d%2b%5bMeddling%5d).
- You can return the spell to their hand, such as with [Venser, Shaper Savant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVenser%2c%20Shaper%20Savant%5d).
- You can tuck the spell with [Commit](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCommit%5d).
- You can steal the spell with [Æthersnatch](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5b%c3%86thersnatch%5d) or [Commandeer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCommandeer%5d).
- In multiplayer games, defeating a player removes all of that player's spells from the stack.  [Door to Nothingness](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDoor%20to%20Nothingness%5d) is the ultimate counterspell.

Finally, in the case described in the question about [Last Word](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLast%20Word%5d) and [Fling](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFling%5d), you could [Twincast](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTwincast%5d) the Fling, and have a copy that is not countered.  The copy of Fling uses the additional costs paid for the original spell.

---

Historic Note: before the April 2018 rules change, uncounterable spells like Last Word had wording like "Last Word can't be countered by spells or abilities."  Rule 608.2b used to have the spell be countered by game rules if all its targets were invalid on resolution.  The only functional difference is for cards that care about what has been countered, notably [Multani's Presence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMultani%27s%5d%2b%5bPresence%5d)

> 608.2b If the spell or ability specifies targets, it checks whether the targets are still legal. ... The spell or ability is countered if
>   all its targets, for every instance of the word “target,” are now
>   illegal.

Comment: Why aren't you able to change Last Word's target to itself?

Comment: @GendoIkari A spell is not a legal target for itself.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Thanks; found it in rule 114.4.

Comment: Killing an opponent removes all of his/her spells from the stack. That is relevant to multiplayer games.

Comment: @Hackworth Door to Nothingness is my favorite counterspell.

Comment: One more way: you can end the turn, e.g. via Discontinuity (although I guess that is technically the same as exiling the spell).

Answer (score 2):

Since the [Dominaria Comprehensive Rules changes](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/news/dominaria-comprehensive-rules-changes-2018-04-13) it does no longer say "by spells or abilities" because rule 608.2b has been changed. To quote:

> 608.2b
>   One of the Dominaria changes was saying that spells can't be countered, dropping "by spells and abilities." This means that spells that fizzle* shouldn't actually be countered anymore—they just go to their owner's graveyard and don't resolve, but they don't use the keyword action of "counter" to do so. This is a nonfunctional change with the exception of one weirdo: Multani's Presence.
>
> *Yes, fizzle. I'm a linguistic descriptivist, and people want a shorter way to express this, so I whole-heartedly endorse saying "fizzle" in non-technical contexts (for example, not in the Release Notes, where I use many more words to express this). We very briefly considered resurrecting it as an official term and rejected it.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the answers already given, the card [Commit // Memory](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCommit%5d%2b%5bMemory%5d) from Amonkhet allows you to put the spell second from top of their library.

Comment: Yeah, this is a way to get around "Can not be countered" as it does not counter the spell, it just relocates it.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your question

> Also, why does Last Word have this extra clause where Akroma, Angel of Fury does not?

You have to remember that

1. Card design standards change over time.
2. The oracle text on the gatherer is the official text on the card.

If you look at the oracle text, both cards now say

> This spell can't be countered.

Comment: The original reason for this difference was a spell with targets would be countered by the game itself when all targets were made illegal, and they had to still word it to allow this automatic countering.

Comment: As for why they are now the same, this is no longer the case, spells with all targets made illegal are not longer countered by game state, they are put into the graveyard without resolving, which is different from countering, so they don't need the ability to be countered by game state anymore.