# Can you still fizzle in response to a spell that can't be countered?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have [Fleeting Image](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFleeting%20Image%5d) in play, and my opponent targets it with [Urza's Rage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUrza%27s%5d%2b%5bRage%5d), am I not allowed to bounce the Fleeting Image in response, since making Urza's Rage fizzle technically counters it?

Comment: Note that "Fizzling" isn't an action you take, but instead an event that happens to a spell because of your actions.

Comment: Note that this scenario is explicitly listed on `Urza's Rage` Gatherer page: `It can be countered by game rules, such as by having all its targets be illegal. Game rules are neither spells or abilities.`

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/24133/9999

Comment: @Zags that question asks how it may be countered. I am asking if the way I am trying to counter it is legal. The answers may be the same.

Comment: @chiliNUT The point is that Urza's Rage says that it "can't be countered by spells or abilities".  The spell being countered as a result of no legal targets isn't a spell or ability.  Fleeting Image's ability isn't what counters Urza's Rage, it only indirectly causes it to be countered by game rules.  Your question using the term fizzle indicates that this is already a question about countering a spell due to the game rule about illegal targets.

Comment: The way I read this question, it inquires about whether it's legal to do an action that would result in a spell that "can't be countered" "being countered. In my mind, this makes it it's own valid question - yet weirdly enough, the accepted answer doesn't answer that part at all. Maybe the questioner should make an edit to be more clear on what the core part of the question is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bounce your Fleeting Image.

The key you're looking for is that Urza's Rage is countered by the game, not a spell or ability. It's just like if you gave Fleeting Image hexproof.  Since hexproof makes it an illegal target, Rage is countered by the game.

> 608.2b If the spell or ability specifies targets, it checks whether the targets are still legal. A target that’s no longer in the zone it was in when it was targeted is illegal. Other changes to the game state may cause a target to no longer be legal; for example, its characteristics may have changed or an effect may have changed the text of the spell. If the source of an ability has left the zone it was in, its last known information is used during this process. **The spell or ability is countered if all its targets, for every instance of the word “target,” are now illegal**. If the spell or ability is not countered, it will resolve normally. Illegal targets, if any, won’t be affected by parts of a resolving spell’s effect for which they’re illegal. Other parts of the effect for which those targets are not illegal may still affect them. If the spell or ability creates any continuous effects that affect game rules (see rule 613.10), those effects don’t apply to illegal targets. If part of the effect requires information about an illegal target, it fails to determine any such information. Any part of the effect that requires that information won’t happen.

Comment: "countered by the game" really helped to clarify this for me!

Comment: It's worth noting that all cards which say "cannot be countered" will also say "by spells or abilities" if they have any targets. Otherwise, you would have a weird situation where a spell tries to fizzle but it can't; so it still resolves, but can't do anything because what it was targeting isn't there / isn't valid.

Answer (score 4):

**You can bounce Fleeting Image, and Urza's Rage will be countered because of it.**

Note the text on uncounterable spells, which always limits the un-counterability to spells and abilities:

> Urza's Rage can't be countered *by spells or abilities.*

If all targets of a spell become illegal before that spell resolves, that spell will be countered by the rules, from which no spell is protected from:

> 608.2b If the spell or ability specifies targets, it checks whether the targets are still legal. A target that’s no longer in the zone it was in when it was targeted is illegal. Other changes to the game state may cause a target to no longer be legal; for example, its characteristics may have changed or an effect may have changed the text of the spell. If the source of an ability has left the zone it was in, its last known information is used during this process. **The spell or ability is countered if all its targets, for every instance of the word “target,” are now illegal.** [..]

Nothing prohibits you from bouncing the Fleeting Image. Since you did bounce it, it is an illegal target for Urza's Rage, which gets countered because of it.

Answer (score 3):

What the other answers fail to address is the reason why you can bounce your [Fleeting Image](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFleeting%20Image%5d), seeing as your question seems to be whether you're allowed to activate the ability in the first place:

**Whether Urza's Rage can be countered or not has nothing to do with whether you're allowed to bounce your creature**.

As the other answers *did* state, [Urza's Rage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUrza%27s%5d%2b%5bRage%5d) will fizzle in this case for not having any legal targets, which is due to the fact that no spell can be protected from being countered by the game rules. Yet, even in situations where it wouldn't be countered - for example when trying to [Counterspell](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCounterspell%5d) it, you're still allowed to cast the [Counterspell](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCounterspell%5d), simply because there's nothing keeping you from targetting [Urza's Rage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUrza%27s%5d%2b%5bRage%5d) or from casting your spell. On resolution, [Counterspell](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCounterspell%5d) will resolve and simply do nothing.

As long as you're not taking an illegal action, the game will progress and work with what you give it, so to speak, as nothing checks for what would happen if something happens. Assuming you are able to pay the cost to activate [Fleeting Image](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFleeting%20Image%5d)'s ability, and nothing else keeps you from activating the ability (such as a spell with Split Second being on the stack, for example), you may do so whenever you have priority - in response to anyone casting a [Urza's Rage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUrza%27s%5d%2b%5bRage%5d), for example.